# Simple Do While script not working, makes no sense why

Tags: powershell

I just wrote this super simple script, and for some reason it's not working, and I have no idea why. Here's the script:

```
Do {

$IP = Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip | Out-String

Write-Host $IP

Start-Sleep 2

} While ($IP = 'xx.xx.xx.xx')

get-process PROGRAM |Stop-Process
```

My get IP line works and returns my public IP, the script stays in the loop and continues to check my IP, if my IP isn't right the first time through the loop it closes the app as it's supposed to do, but if my IP changes while the loop is going, it just starts displaying the new IP and never exits.

I didn't used to have the Out-String at the end but I added that thinking that the IP it was getting back wasn't in a string format. I've tried single, double, and no quotes on the IP in the While line.

I don't understand why this isn't working, it's the simplest thing in the world. My goal is for this to check my IP while my VPN is on, and if the VPN disconnects it kills some apps I have running.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Do I have to use is instead of = on the while line?

Comment: Use `-eq` instead of `=`

Comment: Why does -eq work and = doesn't?

Comment: In Powershell equal comparison operator is `-eq` not `=`

Comment: Yes, what he said ^ . To elaborate, `=` is the _assignment_ operator (make this equal to that), while `-eq` is the _equality_ operator (_is_ this equal to that?)

Comment: Thank you to the both of you, that makes sense, and it works now. FYI, you can only make so many calls to the site before it blocks you. It appears that most sites out there are like that, where they want you to pay for a premium account to be able to hit their site in a script like I'm doing, so I did it another way. I figured out what network adapter my VPN was using, and queried that instead using the command below, which gives me either IP or Disconnected:

    $IP = get-netadapter  -Name "Ethernet 2" |select Status -expandproperty 
    Status